# How can I resolve the distinct issue in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I am trying to get distinct values for my query. I tried like below, but I am not getting proper result, will any one suggest me how to do resolve the issue.

Here the I want to distinct part_id.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=9scx21&s=8#.UupFqT2SzyQ

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DISTINCT` will give you **distinct values** for **all columns** that you are selecting - not just for one of them

Comment: give me query for that

Comment: @marc_s then what is the solution for the above one, any suggestions?

Comment: @pankeel I provided the link above please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think the result is not correct, the rows returned **are** distinct.

DISTINCT is applied to **all** the columns, there's nothing like give me a DISTINCT(p.part_id) and don't care about other columns.

What you probably want is a single row for each part.id

If you don't have any rules which row you want to be returned you can go with a ROW_NUMBER:

```
select *
from 
 (
   select all your columns
      , row_number() over (partition by p.partid order by p.part_id) as rn
   from ....
   where ...
 ) as dt
 where rn = 1
```

If there are some rules to determine which row should be returned (oldest/newest/whatever) you simply *ORDER BY this column DESC* instead of *ORDER BY p.part*
     order by part_id;

Answer (score 0):

Change `SELECT DISTINCT P.PART_ID FROM..` at begining and add `GROUP BY p.part_id` at end.

Distinct must be applied for all columns which values are the same so you can add columns but remenber to add thet to GROUP BY also